# Return model attributes based on OAuth token scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

How could I return a laravel model based on the scopes from the access token the request is using for authorization similar to how discord does it with its identity and email scopes [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object). I'd like to basically 'dynamically' hide/show specific attributes in a model based on the token scope

Would this be something that would be defined in a controller or in the model?

Answer (score 1):

Decided to make use of the [Laravel API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) and the [conditional attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes)

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'username' => $this->username,
            'email' => $this->when($request->user()->tokenCan('email'), $this->email),
        ];
    }
}
```